# logstash and x-forwarded-for on IIS

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I just built an ELK server on Windows so I'm new to the process.  I've read through the docs but am having trouble parsing out my IIS advanced logs, especially x-forwarded-for data as we're behind a load balancer..

My advanced logging is set up to output the data like this:

```
$date,  $time,  $s-ip,  $cs-uri-stem, $cs-uri-query, $s-port, $cs-username, $c-ip,  $X-Forwarded-For, $csUser-Agent, $cs-Referer, $sc-status, $sc-substatus, $sc-win32-status, $time-taken
```

I set up my logstash.conf like this:

```
input {
  tcp {
      host => "localhost"
          type => "iis"
          port => 5044 

  }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "iis" {
        grok {
            match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{IPORHOST:site} %{URIPATH:page} %{NOTSPACE:query_string} %{NUMBER:port} %{NOTSPACE:username} %{IPORHOST:client_host} %{NOTSPACE:useragent} %{NOTSPACE:referer} %{GREEDYDATA:response} %{NUMBER:httpStatusCode:int} %{NUMBER:scSubstatus:int} %{NUMBER:scwin32status:int} %{NUMBER:timeTakenMS:int}"}
        }
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "iis"
        document_type => "main"
  }
}
```

I don't think this is correct as I'm not getting data.  I've scoured the docs but am still having issues and am not sure if there are other steps I need to take, like mapping the fields.

I'm currently using filebeat from one server to push data to my ELK server.  I'm not sure if this is the best way as well (maybe nxlog?).  We don't want to install logstash on the client machines.

Can someone lend me a hand?  It would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Thanks,
George

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving data in your Logstash? Perhaps the port is closed/logstash can't access it. You should check that first. Also if there is anything in the logs or in the output?

Comment: For the mapping, they are not necessary just to put data in ES. For your Elasticsearch index, when dealing with logs it is better to have a [daily index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index), which makes it easier to clean your data afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Filebeat then you need to use the beats input and not the tcp input. See the documentation on [how to setup Logstash for Beats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/logstash-installation.html#logstash-setup).

Essentially you need to replace your tcp input with:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
```

And inside your Filebeat configuration file, set the [`document_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#_document_type) to `iis` so that your filter condition will match.

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    - paths:
        - 'C:\path\to\your\iis\logs\*.log'
      document_type: iis
```